# Function return type

Tags: c#, vb.net

I have a simple function which returns a single column's data from a database based on an inline SQL statement like this (simplified version):

```
Function GetId(ByVal name As String) As Object

    Dim sql As String = "Select Id From table where username = '" & name & "'"

    Using cmd As New SqlCommand
        cmd.Connection = conn
        cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text
        cmd.CommandText = sql
        GetId = cmd.ExecuteScalar
    End Using

End Function
```

If the SQL returns a row it can be NULL or integer, or alternatively SQL does not return anything.

In another part of the code I have:

```
Dim userId As Object = New Object

userId = GetBillingGroupToInvoice(name)
```

Is it OK to use Object as a return type here. If not what should I specify as a return type of this function? This is in VB but answers in C# is also OK.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your function should probably return a [nullable integer](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/b3h38hb0.aspx), returning `Nothing` when your SQL server returns nothing or `DBNull` (if you don't want to make a difference between *No rows returned* and *DBNull*).

```
Function GetId(ByVal name As String) As Integer?

    Dim sql As String = "Select Id From table where username = '" & name & "'"

    Using cmd As New SqlCommand
        cmd.Connection = conn
        cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text
        cmd.CommandText = sql
        Dim result = cmd.ExecuteScalar
        Return If(DBNull.Value.Equals(result), 
                  Nothing, 
                  DirectCast(result, Integer?))
    End Using

End Function
```

---

Then, you would call your method like this:

```
Dim userId = GetBillingGroupToInvoice(name)
If userId.HasValue Then
    'Do something with userId.Value'
End If
```

Answer (score 1):

If the SQL query returns either an integer or a null value, you may want your function to return a nullable int (`int?` in C#) rather than object, for increased type safety.

Answer (score 1):

Cast return type (if not DBNull) from ExecuteScalar to integer. You can return type of nullable int (int? in C#).

Answer (score 1):

You should specify `Integer` return type instead of `Object`.

```
Function GetId(ByVal name As String) As Integer
    Dim sql As String = "Select Id From table where username=@name"
    Dim retValue as Integer = -1
    Using cmd As New SqlCommand
        cmd.Connection = conn
        cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text
        cmd.CommandText = sql
        cmd.Parameters.Add("@name",SqlDbType.VarChar,30).Value=name
        Dim result = cmd.ExecuteScalar()
        if Not IsNothing(result) And Not IsDBNull(result) Then
            retValue=CType(result,Integer)
        End If
    End Using
    return retValue
End Function
```

Comment: Thanks, but if the column is NULL you get Conversion from type 'DBNull' to type 'Integer' is not valid. error with this.